# Is there a way to control the start and end of quick effects?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation

I’m an making a little scene with quick effects: cell fracture, explosion, smoke. But can not find the way to put a time frame on them.

Is there a way to control the time for these quick effects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the simulations depend on the cache and have a control for start and end.

[image]

Comment: Oh I see it. Thank you very much!